# I've intended attach my linear regression result by for loop but got an error. How can I solve it?

Tags: r

I'm a rookie with R. I have a question.
I need test all gene expression values `(dat[,28:63] - numeric)`, according to various clinical variables `(dat[,1:27] - factor)`. 
My initial code was

```
dat <- readRDS("TCGA GLUT data.rds")
str(dat)

a <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Gender, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
b <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Race, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
c <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Age_Dx, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
d <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Recurrence, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
e <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Vital_Status, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
f <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Hashimoto, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
g <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Histologic_Dx, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
h <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Max_Size, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)    
i <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Metastatic_LN, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
j <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ ETE, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
k <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ T_stage, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
l <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ N_stage, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
m <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ Stage, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)
n <- round(summary(lm(SLC2A1 ~ BRAF_V600E, data=dat))$coefficients, 5)

SLC2A1.result <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n)
SLC2A1.result
```

This job is so hard work which was changing all the gene name manually (SLC2A1 -> SLC2A2 -> SLC2A3...) 
So I've made a for loop like this.

```
result <- data.frame()
for (i in 28:63){
 a <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Gender, data=dat))$coefficients
 b <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Race, data=dat))$coefficients
 c <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Age_Dx, data=dat))$coefficients
 d <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Recurrence, data=dat))$coefficients
 e <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Vital_Status, data=dat))$coefficients
 f <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Hashimoto, data=dat))$coefficients
 g <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Histologic_Dx, data=dat))$coefficients
 h <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Max_Size, data=dat))$coefficients     
 i <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Metastatic_LN, data=dat))$coefficients
 j <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ ETE, data=dat))$coefficients
 k <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ T_stage, data=dat))$coefficients
 l <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ N_stage, data=dat))$coefficients
 m <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Stage, data=dat))$coefficients
 n <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ BRAF_V600E, data=dat))$coefficients 
 result[i] <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n)
 }
```

However, I got an error.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , i) : undefined columns selected
```

I can't realized that where is my error and how can I solve it. Please help me!!

Comment: What does `dim(dat)` return? It sounds like it doesn't think there are 63 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that `summary(lm(...))$coefficients` is a 2x4 matrix. So the
`rbind(a,b,c,...)` in your code builds a 28x4 matrix. Then, if you write 
`result[i] <- rbind(a,b,c,...)` you are assigning a matrix to the `i`-th column of 
your result `data.frame`.

I would advise that you create a matrix for every gene, like you did in your first
example and build a list of matrices for every gene. You could then assign names
to the list indices corresponding to the names of your genes. This would result in
code like the following.

```
result <- list()
offset <- 27
for (i in 28:63){
  a <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Gender, data=dat))$coefficients
  b <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Race, data=dat))$coefficients
  c <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Age_Dx, data=dat))$coefficients
  d <- summary(lm(dat[,i] ~ Recurrence, data=dat))$coefficients
  # more...
  gene.mat <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n)
  result[[i - offset]] <- round(gene.mat, 5)
}
# name the indices by creating a character vector "SLC2A1", "SLC2A2", ...
names(result) <- paste0("SLC2A", 1:36)
```

Then you can access a matrix by using result$SLC2A1 for example.